# How to prevent cache-based side-channel attacks in IoT devices

Tags: malware, cloud-computing, third-party, side-channel

The sharing of hardware resources from various vendors in the Internet of things is fundamental for efficient processing in the cloud. The presence of a myraid of clients accessing the same hardware would give rise to exposure to malicious exploits What mitigation methods could be employed to prevent cache-based side channel attacks in the cloud?

Comment: Are you thinking about a specific device or type of device? Otherwise, this is seeming to broad to answer.

Comment: Let's focus on RFIDs for now.

Comment: What sort of cache attacks, are RFID chips vulnerable to?

Comment: There are three primary elements (RFID middleware, event processing, and in-memory data cache) in an RFID concentrator and I was referring to the data cache if it clarifies things.